# "hasNextInt" does not detect subsequent input; where to put "nextLine"?

Tags: java, input

I am brand new at Java and this one is throwing me. Using the below code it loops through for the first question until I enter anything but an integer but after finishing that loop it does not stop for the remaining question.

Through a bit of research and reading I have found that I need to use the in.nextLine() to eat the newline character after the input. However no matter where I place the nextLine() it doesn't work? I thought it would be after the first int input = in.nextInt(); line but that did not work. Any help on where it would go and why?

```
System.out.print("How many CUs per course are remaining in your degree program? Enter any letter to quit: ");
while (in.hasNextInt()) { // Verify input is an integer
    int input = in.nextInt();
    if (input <= 0) // Verify that input is not negative or zero
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number or any letter to quit");
        System.out.print("Add another course or any letter to quit: ");
    } else {
        courseCuList.add(input);
        System.out.print("Add another course or any letter to quit: ");
    }
}
System.out.print("How many CUs do you plan to take per term?");
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int input = in.nextInt();
    // in.nextLine(); This line consumes the \n
    if (input <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole positive number.");
        System.out.println("How many CUs do you plan to take per term?");
    } else {
        cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would only use `nextLine` and `Integer.parseInt`. It's much easier than trying to consume the line-oriented stream "the right way to fix the next scanner read" after different input has been entered.

Comment: Basically, every time you code nextInt() you must follow it with nextLine() to consume the newline char(s) (assuming you have one number per line of input)

Comment: Using nextLine and Integer.parseInt would replace the in.hasNextInt() correct? Bohemian, in that case nextLine() would follow the first int input = in.nextInt() right? I have tried that following each of them and both of them and it still falls through the second input. I have read through many questions on this subject but none seem to apply to my situation. I appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: If this is a duplicate question could you please to point me to a discussion of this that applies to my situation. I am more than willing to do the research and work to find an answer but I am not finding any threads that apply to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read twice.

The exit condition on your `while` loop is `hasNextInt()` - checking to see if the next token is an integer doesn't actually clear that token, which means that the next `nextLine()` is going to read the token, and the subsequent `nextLine()` will read the newline character.

To demonstrate this, place the following between the loops:

```
System.out.println(in.nextLine() + " | " + in.nextLine());
```

For the input `4, 4, A`, you will see the output:

```
How many CUs per course are remaining in your degree program? Enter any letter to quit: 4
Add another course or any letter to quit: 4
Add another course or any letter to quit: A
 | A
How many CUs do you plan to take per term?
```

There are *two* tokens that need to be cleared from the buffer, and neither of them are integers. Because of this, no matter where you put `nextLine()`, it will fail - you need to insert it *twice*. If you only insert it once, the next token won't be an integer, and `hasNextInt()` will fail when the program tries to enter the second loop.

In order to get your program to work, simply insert:

```
in.nextLine(); in.nextLine();
```

before the second loop. (Note that you shouldn't put both this and the print-out in, as this will read *four* times.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in `while (in.hasNextInt())` each call of `hasNextInt` needs to wait for user input, and then test if it is integer or not.

So each time user give integer, condition will be evaluated to `ture`, loop will execute and condition will need to be checked again, and if it is integer loop will execute again. This will go again and again until `hasNextInt` will be able to return false, for instance when user will give non-integer - like letter. But in this case condition in next loop will also return `false` because this non-integer value was not consumed after first loop. To let second loop work you would need to invoke `nextLine` two times

1. to consume line separator after previously put correct integer
2. to consume actual non-integer value

But this may also fail if user will not put any integer before non-integer value because there will be no line separator to consume.

So consider changing your logic to something similar to

```
boolean iterateAgain = true;
System.out.print("give me positive number: ");
while (iterateAgain) {
    // this inner loop will move on only after getting integer
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {//here program waits for user input
        in.nextLine();// consume non-integer values
        System.out.print("that wasn't positive number, try again: ");
    }
    int number = in.nextInt();// now there must be number here
    in.nextLine();// consume line separator
    if (number > 0) {
        System.out.println("you gave " + number);
        // do what you want with this number
        iterateAgain = false;// we can leave loop
    } else
        System.out.print("that wasn't positive number, try again: ");
}
```

If you want to execute next loop then all you need is reset `iterateAgain` value to `true`.

Comment: I would mark both as the answer if I could. Thank you both not only for a valid answer but for the great explanations. Now I know how to fix it and why it wasn't working every way I tried it.